# Place to put parameter object in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, long-parameter-list

I'm new Rails guy and I have problem with the structure of Rails.

My application structure like this

```
- app
- controllers
-- orders_controller.rb
- services
-- get_customer.rb
```

OrdersController receive create order request and return new order. Because Order belongs to Customer. So I create a service name GetCustomer in order to find or create new customer if not exists.

However, the action method in GetCustomer service receive a long parameters. So I need to extract this parameter into another Object. But I don't know where place should I put it in ?

Any advice is graceful for me ! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hi Your questions is not specific though here is my answer based on what you asked. In your service you can simply set an instance variable to the specific param that you want. example below:

```
def initialize(params)
  @phone= params[:phone]
  @something = params[:somthing]
  @email = params[:email]
end
```

You would have to list specific code if you would like a more specific answer.